# C++ Serial Communication Issue

Tags: c++, console, arduino, readfile, serial-communication

I am trying to make a Console C++ program that will be able to communicate through the serial port with my Arduino microcontroller, however I am having a problem with the ReadFile() function:

This is the ReadFile() function code from my C++ Console Program:

```
            if(ReadFile(myPortHandle, &szBuf, 1, &dwIncommingReadSize, NULL) != 0)
            {
                cout<<"FOUND IT!"<<endl;
                Sleep(100);
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<".";
                Sleep(100);
            }
```

The ReadFile function is consistently returning the "False" value, meaning it is not finding anything in the serial port. On the other side of the serial port, I have my Arduino Hooked up with the following code:

```
int switchPin = 4;                       // Switch connected to pin 4

void setup() {
  pinMode(switchPin, INPUT);             // Set pin 0 as an input
  Serial.begin(9600);                    // Start serial communication at 9600 bps
}

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(switchPin) == HIGH) {  // If switch is ON,
    Serial.write(1);               // send 1 to Processing
  } else {                               // If the switch is not ON,
    Serial.write(0);               // send 0 to Processing
  }
  delay(100);                            // Wait 100 milliseconds
}
```

And every time I press a push button, I would send a "1" value to the serial port, and a "0" every time I don't press a push button. Basically, I got the Arduino code from a tutorial I watched on how to do serial communication with the program Processing (which worked perfectly), though I am unable to do the same with a simple Console Application I made with C++ because for some reason the ReadFile() function isn't finding any information in the serial port.

Anyone happen to know why?

P.S.: The complete code in the C++ Console Program can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27844956/c-console-program-serial-communication-arduino

Comment: The number of possible reasons for serial comms not working exceeds the space available in an SO answer to list them all.

Comment: I c. Could you suggest what approach you would take to debug the situation? Possibly a few things you'd check that might be a likely issue?

Comment: Start by trying to read the data with HyperTerminal or a similar serial terminal program. Use it to find out what all the port settings have to be. Then make your program replicate those settings.

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP Very interesting, I'll be checking that out. Did you happen to see anything strange in my C++ Console code by any chance? The full version of the code is in the link I put in the P.S. message of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The ReadFile function is consistently returning the "False" value, meaning it is not finding anything

No, that is *not* what it means.  A FALSE return value indicates that it **failed**.  That is never normal, you must implement error reporting code so you can diagnose the reason.  And end the program since there is little reason to continue running.  Unless you setup the serial port to intentionally fail by setting a read timeout.

Use GetLastError() to obtain the underlying Windows error code.

Comment: You are correct! I misread the msdn document on it. I'll check now if I can see what is up in the manner you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You look to use MS Windows so try to catch the arduino output using [portmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx) first, then you can debug your C++ code.